# Is there a way to tell the OS to drop any buffered outgoing TCP data?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I've got an amusing/annoying situation in my TCP-based client software, and it goes like this:

1. my client process is running on a laptop, and it is connected via TCP to my server process (which runs on another machine across the LAN)
2. irresponsible user pulls the Ethernet cable out of his laptop while the client is transmitting TCP data
3. client process continues calling send() with some additional TCP data, filling up the OS's SO_SNDBUF buffer, until...
4. the client process is notified (via MacOS/X's SCDynamicStoreCallback feature) that the ethernet interface is down, and responds by calling close() on its TCP socket
5. two to five seconds pass...
6. user plugs the Ethernet cable back in
7. the client process is notified that the interface is back up, and reconnects automatically to the server

That all works pretty well... except that there is often also an unwanted step 8, which is this:

.8. The TCP socket that was close()'d in step 4 recovers(!) and sends the remainder of the data that was in the kernel's outbound-data buffer for that socket.  This happens because the OS tries to deliver all of the outbound TCP data before freeing the socket... usually a good thing, but in this case I'd prefer that that didn't happen.

So, the question is, is there a way to tell the TCP layer to drop the data in its SO_SNDBUF?  If so, I could make that call just before close()-ing the dead socket in step 4, and I wouldn't have to worry about zombie data from the old socket arriving at the server after the old socket was abandoned.

Comment: It sounds to me like a bug in Apple's implementation. You *could* set SO_LINGER for the socket to 0, which would eliminate the wait between calling close, and the close actually happening. After `close` has succeeded, no more data should be transmitted though. http://www.unix.org/single_unix_specification_v3/

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: No more data should be *accepted* for transmission through `send()` calls, but previously-written data should still be transmitted.

Comment: @caf: SUS doesn't seem to agree: "If fildes refers to a socket, close() shall cause the socket to be destroyed. If the socket is in connection-mode, and the SO_LINGER option is set for the socket with non-zero linger time, and the socket has untransmitted data, then close() shall block for up to the current linger interval until all data is transmitted." After the linger time expires, the socket is destroyed -- period. No more data accepted *or* transmitted.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: It doesn't say that the socket is destroyed *immediately*.  If `SO_LINGER` isn't set, that just means that the `close()` doesn't block.  [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setsockopt.html) makes this clearer - *"If SO_LINGER is not specified, and close() is issued, the system handles the call in a way that allows the calling thread to continue as quickly as possible."* .

Answer (score 1):

This (data recieved from two different TCP connections is not ordered with respect to each other) is a fundamental property of TCP/IP.  You shouldn't try and work around it by clearing the send buffer - this is fragile.  Instead, you should fix the application to handle this eventuality at the application layer.

For example, if you recieve a new connection on the server side from a client that you believe is already connected, you should probably drop the existing connection.

Additionally, step 4 of the process is a bit dubious.  Really, you should just wait until TCP reports an error (or an application-level timeout occurs on the connection) - as you've noticed, TCP will recover if the physical disconnection is only a brief one.

Comment: Hmm, one problem with that solution would be that the server allows multiple connections from a single client, so dropping the existing connection would cause problems.   Regarding waiting for TCP to report an error:  that was the original design, but the client is part of a control system for a live sound controller, and so waiting 30-90 seconds for TCP to time out really is not an option for us.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner: You'll need to do something a little more complicated then - have the client send an identifier number for each connection and/or a sequence number / timestamp per command so that the server can detect stale connections or out-of-order commands (it's still best handled at the application level).  If your application is such that older commands from the client are completely superceded by newer ones, it sounds like UDP may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to discard any data that is awaiting transmission when you close the socket at step 4 then simply set `SO_LINGER` to 0 before closing.